# How to set up an email address, with the domain name I purchased, all within AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I set up an email address that uses a domain name that I purchased through AWS.

I would like to have that all done in AWS console.

I have checked documentation, wandered around in the console, I didn't find anything in `Route 53` or `SES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be 'all-in' on AWS, then there workmail product is the solution for you:

https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/

Comment: may I use the domain that I have purchased through AWS? That is the most important thing I need.

Comment: Yes, you can use a domain purchased anywhere with workmail.